# Why does PostgreSQL reassign role command, change template database's owner

Tags: database, postgresql

Imagine a database existing called `store_a` with one table products. There is also a user called `store_a_user`. The database, table, data, objects, etc. are owned by `store_a_user`.

I now create a new user called `store_b_user` and a new database called `store_b` by templating the database `store_a` with this command `CREATE DATABASE store_b WITH TEMPLATE store_a OWNER store_b_user`. This creates the new database `store_b` as an exact copy of `store_a`. The only problem is the data/objects are still owned by `store_a_user`. In order to fix this I have to connect to the `store_b` database as the postgres user to reassign all of `store_a_user`'s roles to `store_b_user` by running this command `REASSIGN OWNED BY store_a_user TO store_b_user`.

As the Postgres documentation shows for the [reassign owned](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-reassign-owned.html) command. In order to reassign the role, you have to connect to the database in question as well as connect with a user who has privileges over both users (in our case `store_a_user` and `store_b_user`). Direct quote from the documentation:

> Because REASSIGN OWNED does not affect objects within other databases, it is usually necessary to execute this command in each database that contains objects owned by a role that is to be removed.

Once `REASSIGN OWNED BY store_a_user TO store_b_user` is ran everything inside of `store_b` is now owned by `store_b_owner` which is exactly what I want. The only problem is running that command changes the owner of `store_a` to `store_b_user`, but only the owner of the table not all of the data inside of `store_a`.

The documentation also states that it will affect all "shared objects" owned by the old role and reassigned to the new, direct quote from documentation:

> ...and of all shared objects (databases, tablespaces), owned by this role will be reassigned to new_role

I have a couple of questions:

1. What is a shared object? (I can't seem to find documentation on this)
2. Why does the original `store_a` table change ownership under the reassign owned command when ran with a connection on `store_b` as the `postgres` user?
3. I don't want the behavior described above but if this behavior is suppose to happen or can't be avoided am I forced to manually reassign ownership to store_a?

Comment: I'm happy to add step by step `sql` queries to demonstrate what is going on here, please let me know if if anyone needs that. I am also happy to provide more information as necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have analyzed the situation quite well.

**Answer to 1**

A *shared object* is one that does not belong to a single database, but to the whole database cluster. Examples are `pg_authid`, which contains the users that are common to all databases, and `pg_database`, which contains all databases.

Shared objects are in a special tablespace `pg_global` that corresponds to the `global` subdirectory in the data directory.

**Answer to 2**

Because, as the documentation you quote says, shared objects are also affected, and the database `store_a` is a shared object.

The objects *in* database `store_a` are *not* global objects and are not affected.

**Answer to 3**

You will have to change the ownership of database `store_a` back after you run `REASSIGN OWNED`. There is no better way to do it.

Be comforted: things were much harder before version 8.2, when `REASSIGN OWNED` was introduced.

Comment: Replying to answer 2. So since the table owner is considered a shared object the `REASSIGN OWNED` will always modify the owner of `store_a`?

Comment: No, the *database* (entry in `pg_database`) is the shared object. I have extended the sentence.

Comment: So that is what causes the ownership of the `store_a` database to change on the `REASSIGNED OWNED` query, since the database sits in `pg_database` which is a shared object?

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly.

Comment: Okay perfect thank you so much for your help @Laurenz I'm going to mark this as the answer.