# Bug with REASSIGN OWNED BY in PostreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, ownership

I'm in postgres 9.2. The documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-reassign-owned.html states : `REASSIGN OWNED only affects the objects in the current database`. Exactly what I need but it seems false.
This command changes also the ownership of all databases owned by the old user.

Here is what I did :

> Copy the database :

```
$ sudo -u postgres -i
$ createdb -O faire-pp -T vozatou_db1 test_db
postgres=# \l
                              List of databases
    Name     |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
test_db      | faire-pp | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
vozatou_db1  | vozatou  | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
```

> Permissions of tables in new database are wrong (still the old user) :

```
postgres=# \c test_db
You are now connected to database "test_db" as user "postgres".
test_db=# \d
                        List of relations
 Schema |                   Name                   |   Type   |  Owner  
--------+------------------------------------------+----------+---------
 public | auth_group                               | table    | vozatou
 public | auth_group_id_seq                        | sequence | vozatou
```

> Change it :

```
test_db=# REASSIGN OWNED BY "vozatou" TO "faire-pp";
REASSIGN OWNED
test_db=# \d
                     List of relations
 Schema |                   Name                   |   Type   |  Owner   
--------+------------------------------------------+----------+----------
 public | auth_group                               | table    | faire-pp
 public | auth_group_id_seq                        | sequence | faire-pp
```

> Everything looks good, but :

```
postgres=# \l
                              List of databases
    Name     |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
test_db      | faire-pp | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
vozatou_db1  | faire-pp | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
```

> Why the owner of my original database changed ?

The documentation specifically says : `The REASSIGN OWNED command does not affect the ownership of any databases owned by the role.`

Any insights ?

**UPDATE**: According to a comment below the problem could be related to `shared objects`, I tried to identify what was the shared object in question with `SELECT * FROM pg_shdepend;` but it didn't show me something exploitable.

Comment: I just use `ALTER DATABASE` to restore the ownership of the others databases. As it didn't change the ownership of the databases content. I hope there is no other side effects.

Comment: Please report this as a PostgreSQL bug.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does PostgresSQL reassign role command, change template database's owner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42952018/why-does-postgressql-reassign-role-command-change-template-databases-owner)

Comment: This is no bug.

Comment: I don't see why it would be a duplicate. The documentation relevant to my version 9.2, doesn't speak about `shared objects` whereas it seems to be the case of the subject you referenced.